# Unsubscribe Request conditionally

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, observable

There is a way to unsubscribe request when other request already exist?

In my case I want keep the last request working and cancel the possible others request because each time ngModel changes, a request starting.

I done something like this:

```
  onFieldChange(searchText: string) {

    if(typeof request != 'undefined') request.unsubscribe();

    let request = this.searchService.loadEntities(searchText)

      .subscribe((resp: Search[]) => {

        this.searchResults = resp;
      })
  }
```

In Angular JS this code work fine.

```
if(typeof request == 'object') request.$cancelRequest();
```

With Angular 2 and es6 I have an error "Block-scoped variable 'request' is used before its declaration".

I understand this but what can I do?

Comment: You realize you have used the `request` variable before declaring it right?

Comment: Yea but I test its type, so I test if `request` variable exist like this no ?

Comment: Why don't you assing it to a field? Like `private request` then you can assign to it like `this.request = ..`

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. But I will see the reply of @YavokFain which seems to be most appropriate in my case. Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the switchMap operator that works on two observables and cancels the inner observable (loadEntities) as soon as the outer observable (the field change) emits a new value. You can use the FormControl for your field that automatically emits values as observable items. Take a look at this code sample: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter5/bindings_and_events/app/observables/observable-events-http.ts

Comment: Hum a little bit hard to understand. I will check at this more precisely. Thank's you

Comment: Then start with this code sample to understand how to subscribe to events from an input field managed by a FormControl: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter5/bindings_and_events/app/observables/observable-events.ts

Comment: Yes I'm on it. But in my case I have a form tag wrapped around, so I have to set formGroup directive, create a formBuilder... Isn't the same thing that your link where the formControl.changeValue() is accessible direcly from the constructor.

Comment: Ok. This is good ! And like this I can control with operators the behavior for call my HTTP request :D like debouceTime() and distinctUntilChanged(). I had to do this stuffs manually in angular JS... Thank's you I understand now :)